# Query to create a Table

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm currently working on ASP.NET WebForms and trying to create a table with a query on code-behind.

This is my database schema:
CUSTOMER (ID_CUSTOMER, NAME, SURNAME)
ORDER (ID_ORDER, PRICE, ID_CUSTOMER)

As you can see, ORDER contains a foreign key related to CUSTOMER.
What I would like to do is to get a list of all the customers with their orders on the left and display everything on a table.

Example:

```
Rajesh Surname  ID0001   ID0002   ID0003 
Arkesh Surname  ID0901   ID0022   ID0303
Josh   Surname  ID0501   ID0052   ID5003
```

Till now, I used two QUERIES (the first one to select names, and the second one to select orders) but I don't know if there's a way to merge them.

Comment: *"I don't know if there's a way to merge them"* It's called a `JOIN`. These are a fundamental part the SQL language; I suggest reading some tutorials on the basics of SQL and/or T-SQL (as you're using SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

As **@Larnu** has commented, you need to use [`JOIN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15) something like that

```
SELECT * from ORDER 
JOIN CUSTOMER ON CUSTOMER.ID_CUSTOMER = ORDER.ID_CUSTOMER
WHERE CUSTOMER.Name ='Rajesh'
```

You can get more information/tutorials and great examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) as well.